# How to access a certain button to change the value of a certain text field (in a dynamically created controls)

Tags: c#

i need to use a button to make a number of textboxes with related buttons each button will add 1 to the textbox (that i want to be related to it HOW?)

## i have a windows form with button1 and three panels

==========================================

```
 using System;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace AdvancedCounter
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (panel3.Controls != null)
            {
                var btn = panel3.Controls.Find("_B", true).First();
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);
            }

        }
        int a = 0;
        int counter=0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Location = new Point(0, 100);
            btn.Text = "ADD";
            btn.Name ="_B";
            btn.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(Btn_Click);

            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Name = "_T";
            txt.Location = new Point(500, 100);
            txt.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            txt.Text = a.ToString();
            
            panel3.Controls.Add(txt);
            panel3.Controls.Add(btn);

            foreach (var item in panel3.Controls.Find("_B", true))
            {
                item.Text = "ass";
            }
        }
        
        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      //    MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            
            var txtbx= panel3.Controls.Find("_T", true).First();
            var btnbx = panel3.Controls.Find("_B", true).First();
            a++;
            //      find[1].Dispose();
            txtbx.Text = a.ToString();
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: You may wnat to look into/for lambda

Answer (score 0):

First you are giving same Name property for every TextBox and Button, you should not do that. Instead do like this for example:

```
btn.Name = "_B_"+ counter;
```

So you will have different Name for Buttons and TextBoxes. And in event handler:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string index = btn.Name.Split('_')[2];
    string tbName = "_T_" + index;

    var txtbx= panel3.Controls.Find(tbName, true).First();
    a++;
    txtbx.Text = a.ToString();
}
```